# Is MFC's CListCtrl sorting (SortItems) a stable sort?

Tags: c++, sorting, mfc

Just what the title says - if I provide values of -1, 0 and 1 for the sort callback for a CListCtrl (sort by heading/column) is the sort a [stable sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm)?

Comment: I don't think would matter. The end users aren't that intelligent to see if "Sort" has resulted in stable or unstable sort in the list control.

Comment: @Maybe your users aren't...  I guess I'll just go test for myself.  Pretty useless comment right there.

Answer (score 1):

The first two params of the callback are designed to be the elements to compare on this iteration, the third param is designed to be used for order, column, and other criteria. The callback performs the comparison and returns an integer value representing what direction to move an element, if any.

In that sense it can be a stable sort if you compared lparam ids and did a less than or subtraction comparison ensuring a non-decreasing order. In reality you could implement the callback differently or pass additional sort criteria in the third parameter to do ascending, descending, or some other custom sorting comparison so there is no guarantee.

As a side not it is probably more efficient to maintain a container of data separate from the control like a `std::vector` and perform a stable sort algorithm on that optimized container like `std::sort` then use `LVS_OWNERDATA` style on the `CListCtrl` to draw from the container of data via the `LVN_GETDISPINFO` callback.

Comment: So you're saying that if a value of 0 is returned that internally the control does not know to keep the order relative/consistent with the prior sort?  This doesn't sound right.  It can't be non-deterministic, can it?  I understand what you are saying about doing it ourselves - but there has got to be a defined behavior for the control when the callback returns 0.

Comment: I believe if it returns 0 the order will be unchanged for the current iteration however I was under the impression this could be used to do  a selection sort, heap sort, or some other non-stable sort depending on implementation if you really wanted to.

Comment: OK, thanks.  I guess the best thing to do is for me to test it.

Comment: By default if you do something simple like the MSDN example `return (int)(lParam1 - lParam2);` it will be stable. Perhaps post your sort callbacks and related structures being passed into them here for a closer look?

Comment: if it is stable if the return value is 0 then that works for us.  Thanks